# Can you require a whole set of modules or classes via one require statement?

Tags: crystal-lang

I am trying to import many classes using one `require` statement. Is this possible?

I have the following file structure:

[image: repl-file-structure]

In my `main.cr` I have the following:

```
require "./module-a"
require "./module-b"
require "./module-c"

ModuleA.who_am_i()

ModuleB.who_am_i()

instanceB = ClassB.new
instanceB.who_am_i()

ModuleC.who_am_i()

instanceC = ClassC.new
instanceC.who_am_i()
```

When I run this program, I get the following:

```
Showing last frame. Use --error-trace for full trace.

In main.cr:9:13

 9 | instanceB = ClassB.new
                 ^
Error: undefined constant ClassB

Did you mean 'Class'?
exit status 1
```

`ClassB` is defined in the file `module-b/module-b.cr`. The fix would be to change the require statement to `./module-b/*`. For `module-c`, I defined `ClassC` in its own file. Is there a way to import all classes with just 1 require statement? Or do I have to specify each class I want to require?

I am thinking if there is a javascript equivalent, where I define 1 `index.js` file in a folder that does multiple `modules.export` statements to export all functions and classes.

The following repl describes the whole setup...

[Repl.it Link](https://repl.it/talk/share/Crystal-Lang-Require-Statements/112067)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Isn't the issue more that you would need to access `ClassB` using `ModuleB::ClassB`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the Crystal Programming community on Discord (worth joining - thanks to Blacksmoke16 and jack arthur from the server), I was able to come up with this solution:

**main.cr**

```
require "./**"

ModuleA.who_am_i()

ModuleB.who_am_i()

instanceB = ModuleB::ClassB.new
instanceB.who_am_i()

ModuleC.who_am_i()

instanceC = ModuleC::ClassC.new
instanceC.who_am_i()
```

Although it is not as elegant as Node, it does the job.

Thanks to @matthewm (on the Discord server):

> This solution is requiring all the files and nested files starting
> from the directory the file with the requires is in. One problem you
> might run into with doing only that is that you are defaulting to the
> require order of whatever crystal chooses. If you have a module_c that
> depends on module_b but you do require ./**, Crystal might try to
> require module_c before module_b and it will fail so you will need
> either always require files directly and in the correct order or
> require files individually before requiring everything at once:

```
require "./module_b"
require "./**" # files in here depend on module_b to be loaded first
```

Comment: Yea that seems to be correct. Crystal is definitely a learning journey! Thank so much for looking into this. I'll have to subscribe to that Discord server!